# List data structure to allow querying "does x occur before y"

Tags: data-structures

I have a list of 64-bit signed integers e.g. [10232, 10233, 10234, 10400, 10235, 10236, 10401]

What data structure is most appropriate, given I need to do the following operations on it (ordered by frequency of the operation)

1. Query if one number occurs before another in the list (e.g. is 10233 before 10235)
2. Delete from the front
3. Append to the end
4. Insert a number after another, anywhere in the list (e.g. insert 10402 after 10234). A sentinel value is used to indicate it should be inserted at the top of the list.
5. Delete a number anywhere in the list

Comment: How many integers in the list, typically/worst-case?

Comment: Typically, around 10000 - 2000, worst case, 4000.

Comment: 10K - 2K, worst case 4K? (4K < 10K)

Comment: The name for the data structure I'm looking for turns out to be an order maintanance data structure (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order-maintenance_problem#Data_structure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a map of integer to a node in something like [a rope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28computer_science%29).

A rope is a binary tree. It's actually used for strings, but we can get it to work with minor changes.

Let each node have a "weight" equal to one plus the sum of all the nodes in its left subtree. Each node's value is implicitly defined by these weights, and will correspond to the index in the list. When determining these values, we go from the root to the target node, adding up the weights if we go to the right or the node we're looking for is the target node.

Each node will also need to have a pointer to its parent (so we're able to determine the index of some given node).

Using these combinations of structures, all operations will be supported in O(log n).

Query if one number occurs before another can be done by querying the tree for the indices of both numbers and comparing them. Inserting a number after another can similarly be done by first obtaining the index, and then inserting at that index plus 1.

For example, if we have a tree like this:

```
       .
     /   \
    .     .
   / \   / \
  .   . .   .
 /   /   \
.   .     .
```

The weights will be:

```
       6
     /   \
    3     3
   / \   / \
  2   2 1   1
 /   /   \
1   1     1
```

And the nodes' values will be:

```
       6
     /   \
    3     9
   / \   / \
  2   5 7   10
 /   /   \
1   4     8
```

To get `7` in the above tree, we start from the root and add `6` since we go right. Then we go left, so nothing to do. Then we're at the target node, and there's no left subtree, so we add `1`, giving us `7`.